# How do I run asciiquarium in out-of-the-box ubuntu?

Tags: installation, perl

[Asciiquarium](https://github.com/cmatsuoka/asciiquarium) is a perl script that requires Term::Animation.  What are the appropriate hoops to jump through to get this cpan module into an ubuntu perl install?

```
apt-cache search animation |grep -i perl
```

doesn't seem to find anything like `libterm-animation-perl` to just `apt-get` blindly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perl modules that are not provided as debian package must be installed manually. One way of doing that: download the `Term-Animation-XX.tar.gz` source (XX is a version number), unpack it and do

```
cd Term-Animation-XX
perl Makefile.PL && make && make test
sudo make install
```

or you can use the automatic Perl module installer:

```
sudo cpan Term::Animation
```

During the first run, the installer will ask you a few questions that usually require just hitting Enter to choose the default option.

Comment: I also needed to apt-get install libcurses-perl before cpan succeeded

Comment: `sudo apt-get install build-essential` required if got `Can't exec "/usr/bin/make"` error due to `make` command not found.

Answer (score 1):

You might also like my [PPA for asciiquarium](https://launchpad.net/%7Eytvwld/+archive/ubuntu/asciiquarium).